# Query only keys in _Source document (skip values)

Tags: elasticsearch

Currently "hits" section of response from ES looks like this:

```
[
{"_source":
  {"name" "Long text1"}}
{"_source":
  {"types" "Long text2"}}
]
```

I need to get only field names (values are texts and can be large):

```
[
{"_source":
  {"name" null}
{"_source":
  {"type" null}}
]
```

I can select fields I need ("_source/exclude" section in query),
but I can not find any way to skip values in _Source

Comment: I'm curious about the goal to only get the field names without the values? Why not retrieving the mapping instead?

Comment: @Val I mentioned this in the question: values are quite large. I need keys (from source documents) in specific query, not all keys in index. I do not see how mapping may help with this. Any ideas how to do this with mapping?

Comment: so each of your documents have different keys? Seems weird

Comment: @Val There is set of keys (quite large actually), any document may contain any subset of them.

Comment: You should strive to store documents with different schemas/mappings in different indexes, to prevent having [sparse mappings](https://www.elastic.co/blog/removal-of-mapping-types-elasticsearch#why)

Comment: "...few or no fields in common in the same index leads to sparse..." That is not a case. All documents have same scheme, all documents are of same type, all documents have lot of common fields, but many (most) of fields are optional indeed.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. The fact is that ES stores and indexes JSON documents and it will return key/value pairs, no matter what, because what matters in the end are the values, but your use case might be different, i.e. you only want to see keys. Still curious about your exact use case and why you only need keys.

Comment: Most of the time I query documents, this part is just fine. But sometimes I need to query available keys only (to adjust UI according to available info).